# \ifstrequal in tabular produces spurious spaces

Tags: tables, etoolbox

I'm working on a LaTeX class for my university's thesis format, which requires signature lines on the title page. The sig lines are labelled differently depending on what kind of a thesis it is, so i've used a parametrised \maketitle macro. However, anything except coop results in superfluous spaces in front of the thesis advisor sig lines. A minimum failing example follows.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\siglines}[1][coop]{
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
   \\ \hline
   Student    \\
   \\
   \\ \hline
   \ifstrequal{#1}{coop}{Employer Thesis Advisor~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}{}
   \ifstrequal{#1}{research}{Faculty Thesis Advisor~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}{}
   \ifstrequal{#1}{pp}{Company Liaison~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}{}
   \ifstrequal{#1}{eship}{Faculty Thesis Advisor~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}{} \\
   \\
   \\ \hline
   \ifstrequal{#1}{coop}{Faculty Thesis Advisor}{}
   \ifstrequal{#1}{research}{Committee Member}{}
   \ifstrequal{#1}{pp}{Faculty Thesis Advisor}{}
   \ifstrequal{#1}{eship}{Committee Member}{} \\
   \end{tabular}
}

\siglines[eship]
\end{document}
```

How do i suppress those spaces? It seems like there is no space if coop, and increasing amount of space with research then pp then eship.

Also, question about tex.sx: How do i get it to render the MFE and insert it into my question so i can show how it looks rendered?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Add `%` signs at the ends of the lines where you don't want spaces. A line break is a space as far as TeX is concerned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new line is a space. A space is a space. Use `%` signs to end lines when spaces are not wanted.

For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\siglines}[1][coop]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
      \\\hline
      Student\\
      \\
      \\\hline
      \ifstrequal{#1}{coop}{Employer Thesis Advisor~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}{}%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{research}{Faculty Thesis Advisor~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}{}%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{pp}{Company Liaison~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}{}%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{eship}{Faculty Thesis Advisor~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}{}\\
      \\
      \\\hline
      \ifstrequal{#1}{coop}{Faculty Thesis Advisor}{}%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{research}{Committee Member}{}%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{pp}{Faculty Thesis Advisor}{}%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{eship}{Committee Member}{}\\
    \end{tabular}
  }

  \siglines[eship]
\end{document}
```

[image: trimmed page]

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the `%` to end a line while suppressing space, but somehow it wasn't clicking in my brain.

Comment: @alisonc It is easy to miss this stuff. Especially in your own code. At least, so I find. (Like looking for typos in your own text.)